# WPF disable mouse-wheel-scrolling on a ListView

Tags: wpf

I should disable the mouse-wheel-scrolling for some ListBoxes (View=GridView).

Setting `handled=true` in the standard mouse-wheel-event-handlers is not an option because I need the mouse-wheel-events to be processed in a higher level ScrollViewer (parent of the ListBox).

Is there a possibility to achieve that?